# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Passport

Tags: c#, asp.net, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have upgraded my crm from 2011 to 365.
and now all the aspx pages that I have give me save error which is

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Passport,
>   Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

but the thing is visual studio 2015 for crm 365 does not support Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Passport dll anymore, what can I do to fix this ? 
I added a screen print for you to see the entire error:

[image]

Comment: Where are these ASPX pages hosted?

Comment: in an app under the website in the iis

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you are putting ASPX pages into your CRM IIS application, then that is no longer supported.

[Unsupported customizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx#Anchor_4)

> Creating an Internet Information Services (IIS) application inside the
>   Microsoft Dynamics 365 website for any VDir and specifically within
>   the ISV folder is not supported. The \ISV folder is no
>   longer supported.

I *believe* `Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Passport` is an internal CRM assembly. I'm going to guess its been removed from the 365 installation or moved somewhere else. You could try finding it and including it where you files expect it to be, but thats not something I would advise, might just cause some different types of problems.

I think you will need to change the overall of your application so its supported. E.g. hosting your ASPX files in their own ASP.NET website.

Comment: that what i did, Thank u